# Can you split a table into different pages in Semantic-UI-React?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, semantic-ui-react, ant-design-pro

I am trying Semantic-UI-React.

I did work with Ant Design before.
with Ant Design when you build a table it is spitted into a couple of pages automatically (shows you about 10 rows at each page). 
Can this be achieved in Semantic-Ui-React as well?

I can't find anything in the docs here:

https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/#types-pagination

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, Semantic UI React cannot do automatic pagination. I will have to do it yourself.

Comment: This is kinda weird, it seems like they thought about everything except of this